# PowerShell terminate java process detected by its commandline

Tags: java, powershell, wmic, start-process

I am starting a java process:

```
$global:TS = Start-Process -FilePath "$pathTS\jdk\bin\java.exe" -ArgumentList "-jar","`"$pathTS\TestServer.jar`"" -WorkingDirectory ` "$pathTS" ` -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
```

works fine so far.

Now I am trying to terminate that process:

```
 Invoke-CimMethod -Query 'select * from Win32_Process where CommandLine like "Test-Server"' -MethodName "Terminate"
```

BTW: I cannot use the ID of the process to terminate it since it is changing somehow.

I am new to PS and now stuck.
Maybe someone has in idea.

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Invoke-CimMethod does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the wildcard character `%` to the WHERE clause to find all instances where "Test-Server" is found anywhere in the CommandLine :

```
... WHERE CommandLine like "%Test-Server%"...
```

ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/like-operator